# How to determine overall progress of the STARTUP2 BTree Bottom Up step?

Tags: mongodb

What is a good way to determine the overall progress of the index-building phase of the initial synchronization (STARTUP2) of a new Secondary member? The index-building phase takes a very long time in my case (several days), and it would be great to be able to see where it is in the process.

The log output looks like this:

```
Tue Jan 27 20:04:45.006 [rsSync]    Index: (2/3) BTree Bottom Up Progress: 782212700/946547617  82%
```

As far as I am concerned, this translates to "82% of some object, out of an unknown number of objects of unknown size."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no current way to monitor this progress, although there is a ticket in place to enhance the monitoring of STARTUP2 using rs.status():

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7526
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7019

That said, the time required for this phase is roughly a function of the time required for each index times the number of indexes being by. In turn, the time required for each index is a function of the number of documents in each index.

So if you measure how long it takes to create an index, divide it by the total number of documents in that index. That should give you a rough idea of speed to index a single document. Then multiply that by the total number of documents in all indexes and that should give you an idea of the time remaining.

Now, that's a rough idea - one thing that will impact the total time is the total size of data that needs to be indexed vs. the memory available. If you got to create an index, after another indexed was created that touched the same documents, it may go quite a bit faster if the data is still cached in memory. No way to predict this easily, other than to say if total document size is >> than memory than you will not see much speed up due to previous caching of documents.

Long term I'd vote up https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7019 to see if we can't get this into the queue as it's really painful not to have it for large MongoDB databases.

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible with fixes to [SERVER-7526](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7526) and [SERVER-7019](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7019):

**MongoDB 4.2.1 and above:**

Run in mongo shell: 
`db.adminCommand( { replSetGetStatus: 1 } )`

> If you run replSetGetStatus or the mongo shell helper rs.status() on a member during its initial sync (i.e. STARTUP2 state), the command returns replSetGetStatus.initialSyncStatus metrics.

Here is example output for *initialSyncStatus*:

```
        "initialSyncStatus" : {                                       
                "failedInitialSyncAttempts" : 0,                            
                "maxFailedInitialSyncAttempts" : 10,                                 
                "initialSyncStart" : ISODate("2019-10-29T20:01:12.516Z"),                                      
                "initialSyncAttempts" : [ ],                                       
                "fetchedMissingDocs" : 0,                                     
                "appliedOps" : 0,                                                                              
                "initialSyncOplogStart" : Timestamp(1572379269, 4),                
                "databases" : {                                                                                
                        "databasesCloned" : 3,                     
                        "admin" : {                           
                                "collections" : 4,                                    
                                "clonedCollections" : 4,                            
                                "start" : ISODate("2019-10-29T20:01:13.393Z"),
                                "end" : ISODate("2019-10-29T20:01:14.777Z"),
                                "elapsedMillis" : 1384,         
                                "admin.system.roles" : {                      
                                        "documentsToCopy" : 1,                                                 
                                        "documentsCopied" : 1,                   
                                        "indexes" : 2,                        
                                        "fetchedBatches" : 1,                         
                                        "start" : ISODate("2019-10-29T20:01:13.911Z"),
                                        "end" : ISODate("2019-10-29T20:01:14.196Z"),
                                        "elapsedMillis" : 285                    
                                },
```

**MongoDB 3.4.0 - 4.2.0:**

Execute the 
`db.adminCommand( { replSetGetStatus: 1, initialSync: 1 } )` command on a member in STARTUP2 state

**MongoDB reference:** [replSetGetStatus](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetGetStatus/)

Answer (score 0):

Answer for **MongoDB 5.0 release**.

The initial sync may take some time - be patient. As far as I see it runs in two steps. First MongoDB clones all collections, i.e. it makes a "plain" copy of all collections. You can monitor this by connecting to syncing member and run `rs.status().initialSyncStatus`

```
shard_03:STARTUP2> rs.status().initialSyncStatus
{
        "failedInitialSyncAttempts" : 0,
        "maxFailedInitialSyncAttempts" : 10,
        "initialSyncStart" : ISODate("2022-04-28T08:33:36.519Z"),
        "totalInitialSyncElapsedMillis" : 6548240,
        "initialSyncAttempts" : [ ],
        "approxTotalDataSize" : NumberLong("488957278026"),
        "approxTotalBytesCopied" : NumberLong("519033102224"),
        "remainingInitialSyncEstimatedMillis" : -379443,
        "appliedOps" : 0,
        "initialSyncOplogStart" : Timestamp(1651134817, 16004),
        "totalTimeUnreachableMillis" : NumberLong(0),
        "databases" : {
                "databasesToClone" : 2,
                "databasesCloned" : 5,
...
                "plau01mipmed0" : {
                        "collections" : 9,
                        "clonedCollections" : 8,
                        "start" : ISODate("2022-04-28T09:56:10.907Z"),
                        "plau01mipmed0.sessions" : {
                                "documentsToCopy" : 16449103,
                                "documentsCopied" : 16891103,
                                "indexes" : 4,
                                "fetchedBatches" : 242,
                                "bytesToCopy" : NumberLong("3816816827"),
                                "approxBytesCopied" : NumberLong("3918735896"),
                                "start" : ISODate("2022-04-28T09:56:10.907Z"),
                                "end" : ISODate("2022-04-28T09:59:02.068Z"),
                                "elapsedMillis" : 171161,
                                "receivedBatches" : 242
                        },
                        "plau01mipmed0.ignored" : {
                                "documentsToCopy" : 8095615,
                                "documentsCopied" : 5711111,
                                "indexes" : 2,
                                "fetchedBatches" : 86,
                                "bytesToCopy" : 1966181814,
                                "approxBytesCopied" : 1382088862,
                                "start" : ISODate("2022-04-28T10:22:17.332Z"),
                                "receivedBatches" : 86
                        }
```

After some time you should get result like

```
shard_03:STARTUP2> rs.status().initialSyncStatus.databases    
...
{ 
  ... 
  "databases" : { 
    "databasesToClone" : 0, 
    "databasesCloned" : 7
    }
}
```

After that MongoDB starts to apply the oplog. You can monitor it with this command:

```
shard_03:STARTUP2> rs.status().members.filter(x => x.name == db.hello().me).forEach(
   x => printjson(
      {
         date: ISODate(),
         name: x.name,
         stateStr: x.stateStr,
         optimeDate: x.optimeDate,
         oplog_BacklogSeconds: (ISODate() - x.optimeDate) / 1000
      }
   )
)

{
   "date" : ISODate("2022-04-28T11:27:42.111Z"),
   "name" : "d-mipmdb-sh2-03:27018",
   "stateStr" : "STARTUP2",
   "optimeDate" : ISODate("2022-04-28T09:40:50Z"),
   "oplog_BacklogSeconds" : 6412.111
}
```

Again, you need to be patient. `oplog_BacklogSeconds` should **slowly** decrease. However when you run `rs.status().initialSyncStatus.appliedOps` then you see constantly increasing number.

Sooner or later, the member state should go to `SECONDARY`. As this time the sync is not fully done, i.e. `oplog_BacklogSeconds` may still show a high number, but it should decrease rather fast. When it becomes 1-2 Seconds then it is fully done.