# Why doesn't Mongo Replica Node sync compeletly?

Tags: mongodb, synchronization, replicaset, mongodb-replica-set

[Mongo index size monitoring on my heavy collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKeGX.png)I had 3 node mongodb replicaSet cluster (V=6.0.5), One of nodes crashed, now I have a rs with 2 members,
and i'm trying to join 3rd node. My data size is around 3TB on each node (2TB collection data,1TB indexes).
3rd node syncs until 2TB and become SECONDARY from STARTUP2, but the problem is since it does not have indexes, Requests that go to this node will slow down the whole system.

(i had three node mongo replicaset,
one node crashed,
i joined a new server as a replicaset (third node).
in my two other servers when i get df -Th size of mongodb partition is 3TB TB,
but new node size of mongodb partition is 2.4TB and state is Secondary when i get rs.status().
is it okay?)

I have a very stable network connection between nodes.
I tried multiple times (cleared db directory,used rsync, ...).

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28180167/how-to-determine-overall-progress-of-the-startup2-btree-bottom-up-step/72044334#72044334 Be patient and monitor the sync. While sync is running, requests should not go to this node unless you force it.

Comment: If it changed from startup2 to secondary, it is done building indexes.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit
 i checked your reffered link(i also edited my question),

{
  date: ISODate("2023-12-11T15:16:15.022Z"),
  name: '172.16.52.104:27017',
  stateStr: 'SECONDARY',
  optimeDate: ISODate("2023-12-11T15:16:13.000Z"),
  oplog_BacklogSeconds: 2.022
}





does this response mean that synchronization is finished?
still the size of mongo partion on new node is 600 GB smaller than other nodes.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I also attached a new image,
this is what monitoring show.
the blue line is my newly joined node.
please check it.